# Querying through a list of documents and its contents with Sharepoint 2010 Services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently developing an application using Sharepoint 2010 Web services to access data from a Sharepoint server. Im using ListData.svc to get items of a particular list of documents saved in the SP server, and my aim is to be able to *search* through this list, including its documents contents. I have been researching through options, and have seen stuff like asmx, enterprise search API, query services, etc., but I am not quite sure if this would really crawl through the file contents.

Can you enlighten me on what web service to use to be able to search through a particular list of files-- all its properties and file contents? Similar to the search option in an actual Sharepoint site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Id expect a quick google on "Sharepoint 2010 search api" to yield up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcspsearch(v=office.14).aspx which says "Search in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 exposes its search functionalities through the Query Web service. This allows you to access SharePoint Foundation Search results from client applications and Web applications outside of the context of a SharePoint site."

I guess if you read those docs, the solution will be in there.